# asp webforms textbox validatod max 5 integers and *

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I am searching for a solution to make a textbox accept at max 5 integers and the asterix *

thanks

```
enter <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="Ordre" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Entrer 5 chiffres au maximum !"
                    ValidationExpression="^\d+$">
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>code here
```

Comment: Change the pattern in `ValidationExpression="^\d+$"` ?

Comment: Ah by the way, you mean *5 integers* or *5 numericals characters* ?

Comment: 5 integers. I want to add the character * so I can enter at 5 integers that can contain *.
example : 1234* or *100 ....

Answer (score 0):

you could change the pattern to `^[\d,*]{0,5}$`
Try [this tool](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test and [this page](http://regexstorm.net/reference) to get reference

Hope it helps!